# Cannot view usb flash drive on My Computer

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

On my computer, I use Windows 7  and I'm unable to read any USB flash drive. When I insert the USB flash drive, it does appear on Device Manager and on Disk Management but when I check on My Computer, it does not appear.

I tried to open and explore from Disk Management but it shows error 
"`This operation has been cancelled due to restrictions in effect on this computer. Please contact your system administrator`"

> **Solution that I Tried:**
>
> 1. Uninstalling the USB mass storage driver and rebooting.
> 2. Change drive letter and path in Disk Management.
> 3. Scan for hardware changes for Portable Devices on Device Manager.

I had search and tried above solution but still failed to view my USB flash drive. May I know what is the main reason behind all this and is there any solution.

Thanks in advance.

** The flash drive works on other computers.

Comment: Does the flash drive work on other Windows 7 machines?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.